# What to do if a tag is regularly used wrong (acronym has more than one meaning)?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-tips

There is the [ota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ota) tag, which is described in the Tag Wiki as *Over-the-air wireless communication*.

There are also many questions about the HP QualityCenter OTA (Open Test Architecture) API which are (wrongly) tagged with the [ota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ota) tag (16 out of the last 50 `ota`-tagged questions are about the Open Test Architecture, not about Over-the-air wireless communication).

What is the best thing to do about it? Only retagging all Open Test Architecture questions? Also the old ones? Or is there something which could/should be done about the tag?

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/165773)